# Error in code used to calculate no. of sweets a customer buys providing banknotes

Tags: c

A customer points at some kind of sweets and gives several banknotes to the seller. This means that he wants to buy a positive number of sweets of that kind. He doesn't tell the exact number of sweets he wants to buy. The only thing Ann knows is: an 'adequate' customer won't give any extra banknotes. It means that if you throw away any banknote, the resulting amount of money won't be enough to buy the wanted number of sweets.

Ann has to determine the number of sweets the customer wants. Help Ann write a program which determines this number or tells that it's impossible.

Input

The first line of the input contains a single integer T, the number of test cases (no more than 20). T test cases follow. Each test case consists of two lines. The first of these lines contains two integers N and X (1 ≤ N, X ≤ 100) separated by a single space. N is the number of banknotes given by the customer. X is the cost of a single sweet of the chosen kind. The second of these lines contains N space-separated integers Ai (1 ≤ Ai ≤ 100), the values of the banknotes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int main(void)
{
    int  n = 2, x=10;
    int a[2] = { 20,50};
    int sum = 0;
    int min = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + a[i];
        if (min>a[i + 1])
        {

            min = a[i];


        }

    }
    printf("%d %d\n", sum, min);//output -858993390, -858993460
    int y= sum % x;
    int k = sum / x;
    if (y- min > 0)
        printf( "-1");// output -1
    else
        printf( "%d\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: It should be `i < n`, not `i <= n`

Answer (score 2):

`for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`. You have allocated array size of 2. That means you have control over index 0 and 1. But you are trying to access index 2.

Answer (score 1):

this line, even after the correction of the 'for' statement, will access beyond the end of the a[] array, resulting in undefined behavior.

```
if (min>a[i + 1])
```

The posted code, even if these two errors are corrected, does not implement the problem set.

caveat: The following code assumes that all values are integers

comments within the code indicate each step being performed

```
/*
 * ***********************************************************************************************
   The first line of the input contains a single integer T, the number of test cases (no more than 20). 
   T test cases follow. 

   Each test case consists of two lines. 

   The first of these lines contains two integers N and X (1 ≤ N, X ≤ 100) separated by a single space.
   .... N is the number of banknotes given by the customer. 
   .... X is the cost of a single sweet of the chosen kind. 

   The second of these lines contains N space-separated integers Ai (1 ≤ Ai ≤ 100), the values of the banknotes
 * ************************************************************************************************
 */

#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), perror(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main( void )
{
    // input number of test cases
    int testCases;
    if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &testCases ) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for number of test cases failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    for( ; testCases; testCases-- )
    {
        int numNotes;
        int eachCost;
        //get N_X line
        if( 2 != scanf( "%d %d", &numNotes, &eachCost ) ) 
        {
             perror( "scanf for numNotes and eachCost failed" );
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        // read bank notes and calculate sum
        int totalNotes = 0;
        int singleNote;

        for( int j=0; j < numNotes; j++ )
        {
            if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &singleNote ) )
            {
                perror( "scanf for single note failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            totalNotes += singleNote;
        } // end for each bank note

        // calculate number of candies that can be purchased, 
        // given the totalNotes and eachCost

        if( totalNotes >= eachCost )
        {
            int numCandies = totalNotes / eachCost;
            printf( "Number of candies: %d\n", numCandies );
        }

        else
        {
            printf( "not enough notes to purchase any candies\n" );
        }

        // follow each test case with a blank line
        printf( "\n" );
    } // end for each test case
} // end function: main
```

Comment: user3629249 thanks for answer.i'm new to coding so could you please explain me why my code wouldn't implement problem set.I'll be obliged....

Comment: Ill try to explain:  For simplicity, treat the inputs as if they were in a file, then run the code via: `./myCode < myData.txt`  (the following points are related to the description of the data.  2) the first line of the input contains a number.  That number represents the number of test cases.  so read that number and use it to drive a `for` loop 3) for each test case, there will be two lines of input.  the first line of each test case contains 2 numbers.  The first number is the number of numbers in the second line.  The second number is the cost of an individual candy  (cont)

Comment: use the 'number of numbers' drive a `for` loop.  4) In each iteration of this second `for` loop, read one number and add that number to a total value, (where that total value was initially set to 0)   5) after getting all the inputs for this test case, then divide the total value by the cost of a single candy.  The result is the number of candies that can be purchased.   6) if the result of the divide is 0, then output the NO CANDIES message, otherwise output the NUMBER OF CANDIES message.    7) loop back to top of 'test case' loop for the next test case.   (cont)

Comment: Your code does NONE of the above steps.  Rather, it tries to do a single test case, in memory without inputting any of the actual data.  Even then, it does not calculate the total correctly, it contains some 'useless' fluff about a 'min' variable which has nothing to do with the problem.  Your code performs a 'modulo' (%) operation,  A 'modulo' gets the remainder, which is not of interest to this problem.